# O que javascript:nomeDeFuncao(); faz?

Tags: javascript

Olá eu sou iniciante em javascript e bisbilhotando o código alheio eu achei o seguinte trecho:

```
javascript:nomeDeFuncao();
```

O que é que isso faz?

Eu já vi código assim:

```
nomeDeFuncao();
```

Mas essa parte de " : " é novidade pra mim.
(Eu achei isso pelo Breakpoints do Devtools)

Agradeço desde já a ajuda.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Provavelmente você viu o uso de *javascript:* dentro de um link.

É uma prática muito utilizada para invocar um javascript no click do link:

```html
<a href="javascript:alert('HELLO');"> H E L L O</a>
```

Comment: Olá jovem, muito interessante. eu posso usar isso em outros tipos de atributos?

Comment: sim:
Voce pode usar por exemplo: onClick="javascript:xpto()".

Comment: onClick="xpto()" funcionaria tambem

Comment: Ao pessoal que esta negativando, é importante informar o motivo.